# my spring-boot( Kotlin) Controller don't work that return String

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to make spring-boot project in Kotlin.

but my Controller don't work..
I want open html file So I prepared upload.html file in resoureces/templates

[image]

The following method return String:(
source code is here

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class RestApiController {
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestApiController::class.java!!)

@Autowired
lateinit var parsingservice : ParsingService

@GetMapping("/index")
fun index(response : HttpServletResponse): String {
    return "upload"
}
```

index method is return "upload" and I expected that open upload.html Page  in resourecesPackage.
I studied that when method return String in Cotroller spring-boot framework  scan that resoureces/templates Path So We can just write htmlfiles name without .html

I searched this problem in this site and I found that java9jdk not support spring-boot yet So I'm reinstalled java8jdk and change project setting.
but that didn't work.

this is my maven setting.

```
<name>jsonparser</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.2.10</kotlin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
                <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

how can I open htmlpage?
thank you for reading
have a nice day:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to return the `upload.html` template so your controller is not a [RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html). Controllers annotated with `RestController` will just return the response body. This means your get mapping will just return the String "upload".

Replace the `RestController` annotation with `Controller` and it will work.

Comment: thank you very much! I try it!  and I'll study what is mean RestController exactly! have a nice day!:)